Could not load assembly 'Migrations'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'WebProject in C#
I tried to create this project structure to move my C# migrations into separate class library. enter link description here
I don't understand that if WebProject contains DataModels and Migrations contains DataModels, by creating migrations with the command
dotnet ef migrations add MyNewMigration --startup-project WebProject --project Migration

why it says to me that Could not load assembly 'Migrations'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'WebProject '. It would create circular dependencies.
